# How do I register the PrimeFaces ClientValidator in my web application?

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

my question is how do i register my custom EmailValidator so that p:clientValidator will be able to use my custom EmailValidator on validating my p:inputText? I implemented ClientValidator interface from org.primefaces.validate.ClientValidator but my custom validator is still not being used by the  code.

My code is shown below.

EmailValidator.java

```
@FacesValidator("emailValidator")
public class EmailValidator implements Validator, ClientValidator {
      private Pattern pattern;
      private static final String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[\\w-\\+]+(\\.[\\w]+)*@[\\w-]+(\\.[\\w]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,})$";
      public EmailValidator() {
          pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
      }

      @Override
      public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
            if(!pattern.matcher(value.toString()).matches()) {
                  throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "Invalid Email format."));
            } else {
                  // Code to check if email already exists in the database.
                  // 'email exists' is only a pseudocode.
                  if (email exists) {
                      throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "Email already exists in database."));
                  }
            }
      }

      @Override
      public Map<String, Object> getMetadata() {  return null; }

      @Override
      public String getValidatorId() {  return "emailValidator"; }
}
```

index.xhtml (example filename only):

```
... (other code)
<h:outputText value="Email"/> <span class="required-asterisk">*</span>
<p:inputText id="studentEmail" value="#{StudentAdd.student.email}" 
             required="true" styleClass="form-input-fields" 
             requiredMessage="Required.">
    <!-- I want these two to work. -->
    <f:validator for="studentEmail" validatorId="emailValidator"/>
    <p:clientValidator event="blur"/>
    <!-- I used this code before but whenever I submit the form the error message disappears so I don't use this code.-->
    <!-- <p:ajax update="studentEmail,studentEmailMsg" event="blur"/> -->
 </p:inputText>
 <p:message id="studentEmailMsg" for="studentEmail"/>
... (other code)

<p:commandButton id="saveUserInfo" value="Next" ajax="true" validateClient="true" partialSubmit="true" process="@this,...,studentEmail"/>
```

NOTE: I already added the context-param primefaces.CLIENT_SIDE_VALIDATION to true in my web.xml.

NOTE: I'm using JSF 2.2.16 Mojarra and primefaces-6.2.RC2.

NOTE: Changing ajax to false of commandButton will solve the problem but I want it to be ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have implemented js counterpart of emailvalidator.
Refer script section in primefaces showcase.
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/custom.xhtml